# List all properties files in classpath and read them in java

Tags: java, io

I would like to list all properties files in classpath and would like to read them one after another. Looked into getClass().getResourceAsStream(name) method but that doesn't seem to like wild card characters in name. Is there an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

@gtgaxiola answered java properties, if thats not what you want here is how to find property files;

First list all JARs on your class path with

```
String value = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Then look in each jar for *.properties file

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.jar");
Enumeration zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = ((ZipEntry)zipEntries.nextElement()).getName();
    if (name.matches(".*\\.properties")){
        ...
    }
}
```

Then read each text file

```
InputStream input = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(inputStream);
String value = prop.getProperty("key");
```

Comment: ClassLoaders don't have to use the java.class.path system property.  This will not work in a Java EE environment.  I'm guessing it will not work in a Java Web Start environment either.

Comment: @VGR please let us know the solution for non standard JREs. (as the question did not specify which Java, assuming Java Standard Edition seems like the correct thing to do)

Answer (score -1):

In general, the answer is no: There is no easy way to achieve this.  Java resources are not meant to be listed.  You need to know exactly what resource you want to access, ahead of time.

Some environments create custom ClassLoaders which obtain classes and resources in ways considerably more complex than just reading a .jar file.

The most portable and reliable thing to do is to keep a list of your property files in a known resource location.  For instance, you might package a file named `property-file-list.txt` in your .jar file:

```
Collection<String> propFiles = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader propFileList =
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(
                "property-file-list.txt"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = propFileList.readLine()) != null) {
        propFiles.add(line);
    }
}

// ...

for (String propFile : propFiles) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try (InputStream propStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream(propFile))) {
        props.load(propStream);
    }

    // Process props...
}
```

A less desirable alternative is to assume the current ClassLoader is a URLClassLoader, and to try to scan all of the URLs in the classpath, using an approach similar to what user1133275 described:

```
Map<String, Properties> allProperties = new HashMap<>();

ClassLoader classLoader = MyApplication.class.getClassLoader();
if (classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
    for (URL url : ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs()) {
        try (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()))) {

            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String name = entry.getName();
                if (name.endsWith(".properties")) {
                    Properties props = new Properties();
                    props.load(zip);

                    allProperties.put(name, props);
                }
                zip.closeEntry();
            }
        }
    }
}
```